# Click anywhere in row in v-data-table and move to another page

Tags: vue.js

I have a v-data-table like this

```
// template
<v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="visitors"
        :search="search"
        item-key="name"
        class="elevation-1"
        @click:row="(item) => clickRow(item.caseId)"
      >
</v-data-table>

//script
clickRow(id){
      this.$router.push({name: "VisitDetails", params: {id: id}});
    },
```

I want to get the `caseId` property of an item (a row) whenever user click anywhere in a row, and move to another page with that `caseId` as route params. This doesn't work. How do I fix this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#events-click:row):

> *"This event provides 2 arguments: the first is the item data that was clicked and the second is the other related data provided by the item slot."*

Which means

```
@click:row="(item) => clickRow(item.caseId)" ❌
```

should be:

```
@click:row="(_, item) => clickRow(item.caseId)" ✅
```

(where `_` is the clicked cell data, in case you need it).

---

I tend to only specify the handler:

```
@click:row="onRowClick"
```

and manage the params in the handler:

```
methods: {
  onRowClick(cellData, item) {
    // go wild...
  }
}
```

---

1. Always read docs
2. `console.log()` is your friend.
3. When you feel lazy, (like I do, most times), skip step 1 and power up step 2.
   Spread and log all arguments:

```html
@click:row="onRowClick"
```

```js
 ...
 methods: {
   onRowClick(...args) {
     // this will log all arguments, as array
     console.log(args);
   }
 }
```